# Can I make an SQL query do two matches on every row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have an unusual SQL table (not mine) which has the following fields (among others):  `last_name, primary_name, secondary_name`, denoting married couples. The last name is assumed to be shared (not very modern, I know), and if it's not a couple, then either the `primary_name` or `secondary_name` may be NULL. (The table also has several duplicates.)

What I want to do is get a list of all names ("first last") in the database, alphabetized in the usual manner. Right now I'm doing two passes through the database using PHP and PDO:

```
$qstr = "SELECT DISTINCT primary_name, last_name 
            FROM members 
            WHERE primary_name IS NOT null
            ORDER BY last_name, primary_name";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($qstr);
$sth->execute();
// output the results

$qstr = "SELECT DISTINCT secondary_name, last_name 
            FROM members 
            WHERE secondary_name IS NOT null
            ORDER BY last_name, secondary_name";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($qstr);
$sth->execute();
// output the new results
```

But the end result isn't alphabetized because the second pass starts over again.

How can I get all the names at once, alphabetized completely? Is there a way to do this in SQL, or do I need to build two arrays and re-alphabetize them in PHP afterwards?

**EDIT** 
The database looks something like this:

```
last_name  primary_name   secondary_name
----------------------------------------
Abrams     Joe            Susan
Miller     Sam            Abby
```

The desired output would be something like this:

```
["Joe Abrams","Susan Abrams","Abby Miller","Sam Miller"]
```

Instead, if the first pass gets all the husbands and the second pass all the wives, I'm getting something like this:

```
["Joe Abrams","Sam Miller","Susan Abrams","Abby Miller"]
```

Comment: Can you post an example of output you want to see (using say 4 or 5 different cases of name combinations)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to use UNION...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT primary_name AS pri_sec_name, last_name 
    FROM members 
   WHERE primary_name IS NOT null

  UNION

  SELECT secondary_name AS pri_sec_name, last_name 
    FROM members 
   WHERE secondary_name IS NOT null
)
  AS data
ORDER BY
  last_name, pri_sec_name
```

***NOTE:*** `UNION` *(as opposed to `UNION ALL`)* will de-duplicate the results.

Another is to do a join on a mapping table.

```
SELECT
  members.last_name,
  CASE WHEN map.mode = 1 THEN members.primary_name ELSE members.secondary_name END AS pri_sec_name
FROM
  members
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 1 as mode UNION ALL SELECT 2 as mode) AS map
    ON (map.mode = 1 AND members.primary_name   IS NOT NULL)
    OR (map.mode = 2 AND members.secondary_name IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY
  1,
  2
```

Comment: UNION is one of those things I'd forgotten a long time ago because of lack of use. This seems to work, but can you explain the `AS data` part of the query to me?

Comment: @Blazemonger - It's just to wrap everything up into a sub-query, and then give that sub-query a name.  This is often known as an *in-line view* because you treat your sub-query as a view.  `SELECT * FROM (<any-query-here>) AS MyViewName`

Comment: This is my first time seeing a mapping table. Is there any good reason, performance-wise, to prefer one approach to the other? I'm getting 500-1000 total names in the result table.

Comment: @Blazemonger - Assuming you have an INDEX that makes the `WHERE x IS NOT NULL` simple to lookup, then the first version can be quicker *(1000 rows is so small that this may not be true in your case)*.  The second version, however, can often reduce the amount of duplicated code, and/or be expanded to be flexible whilst being *(relatively)* maintainable.

Comment: I like the 2nd version. There is no need for the external Select and the parenthesis in the 1st version.

Comment: Using the first query, "results took 0.0037 sec" -- I think that's fast enough for our purposes.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly, I think you are looking for something like this:

```
select distinct coalesce(primary_name, secondary_name) as pri_sec_name,
    last_name
from members
where coalesce(primary_name, secondary_name) is not null
order by last_name,
    coalesce(primary_name, secondary_name)
```

**Update**

It sounds like in some cases you have one row for a last_name, where both primary_name and secondary_name are populated. The query below should give you the output you want (sorry, no COALESCE this time):

```
select last_name, pri_sec_name
from (
    select primary_name as pri_sec_name, last_name from members where primary_name is not null
    union all
    select secondary_name as pri_sec_name, last_name from members where secondary_name is not null
) a 
order by last_name, pri_sec_name
```

Comment: First time I've heard of `coalesce`. What will be the output of this SQL? It looks to me like I'm still getting one result row for every one table row, when (most of the time) I need two result rows for every table row.

Comment: COALESCE(value,...)

Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Comment: @IvanMarjanovic Yes, I looked that much up myself. ;-)

Comment: @Blazemonger I assumed you had multiple rows for each last name. I've provided an alternate query above.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
SELECT primary_name AS name
     , last_name 
  FROM members 
  WHERE primary_name IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT secondary_name
     , last_name 
  FROM members 
  WHERE secondary_name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY last_name, name
```

Another rewrite is using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(primary_name, secondary_name) AS name
     , last_name 
  FROM members 
UNION ALL
SELECT secondary_name
     , last_name 
  FROM members 
  WHERE primary_name IS NOT NULL
    AND secondary_name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY last_name, name
```

The 2nd version may be faster but it may show duplicate results. If more example, you have these rows, one `Joe Jackson` married to `Susan` and one married to `Lea`:

```
last_name  primary_name   secondary_name
----------------------------------------
Jackson    Joe            Susan
Jackson    Joe            Lea
```

The first query qould show:

```
name   last_name
-----------------
Joe    Jackson 
Lea    Jackson 
Susan  Jackson
```

while the second would have "duplicates":

```
name   last_name
-----------------
Joe    Jackson 
Joe    Jackson 
Lea    Jackson 
Susan  Jackson
```

Which is more proper, depends on your specs.